# Error while Integrating graphite and locust

Tags: python, graphite, locust

I am trying to send results from locust to graphite by using following

```
def __init__(self):
    super(MyLocust, self).__init__()
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.connect( ("localhost", 2003) )
    locust.events.request_success += self.hook_request_success 

def hook_request_success(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length):
    self.sock.sendall('%s %d %d\n'% ("performance." + name.replace('.', '-'), response_time,  time.time())) def

def exit_handler(self):
    self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.sock.close()
```

I am getting the following error **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Answer (score 0):

sock.sendall() expects a bytes-like object.

Encode the string before passing it to sendall, changing the line to something like

```
self.sock.sendall(('%s %d %d\n'% ("performance." + name.replace('.', '-'), response_time, time.time())).encode())
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives the error  'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: The brackets are placed wrong, try: self.sock.sendall(('%s %d %d\n'% "performance." + name.replace('.', '-'), response_time,  time.time()).encode())

Comment: still having an error TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: ah, still a bracket missing. `self.sock.sendall(('%s %d %d\n'% ("performance." + name.replace('.', '-'), response_time, time.time())).encode())`

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment